# Is it possible to switch from Start state to End state in android MotionLayout using Java/Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-motionlayout

I am working on an android project that uses `MotionLayout`. Long story short, I want to programmatically switch between the Start and End states using Java. Say, this should happen on clicking a button. So I am looking for something like this:

```
MotionLayout myMotionLayout = findViewById(R.id.myMotionLayout);
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

button.setOnClickListener( v -> {
  // some code that switches the state
}
);
```

I did a lot of Google but could not find something like that. I came across a method of the MotionLayout named `setTransitionListener`, but it is used for doing things during the change, not to trigger the change.

I don't know what to do. Can anyone help me with this? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `myMotionLayout.transitionToEnd()` and `myMotionLayout.transitionToStart()`:

```
MotionLayout myMotionLayout = findViewById(R.id.myMotionLayout);
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

button.setOnClickListener( v -> {
    if(myMotionLayout.getCurrentState() == R.id.start_state) {
        myMotionLayout.transitionToEnd()
    } else {
        myMotionLayout.transitionToStart()
    }
  }
);
```